# Does SDL Web8 support selenium testing tool for automation testing?

Tags: web8

SDL Web8 support selenium testing tool for automation testing? any one have idea...

Comment: Selenium is testing UI so I dont think there is any limitation that web 8 will have on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen the post below, although written for 2013, the principles should still apply for Web 8, see Andrey Marchuk's answer:

[Automated CME functional validation after upgrade, hotfix or patch installation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11312/automated-cme-functional-validation-after-upgrade-hotfix-or-patch-installation/11313#11313)

Also Dominic Cronin provides a brief and concise direction in his blog post:
http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/on-line-resources-for-the-agile-tridion-development-talk

The article even includes the (coded) demo given during the 2014 Tridion Developer Summit along with the slides discussing various approaches for automated testing.

Comment: This article mention support SDL Tridion 2011/2013. my question is  it will support SDL Web8?

Comment: Selenium allows you to drive the browser, so the version of Tridion is not particularly relevant.